# How to show thanku popup only, if user alredy submitted the form in magento 2 untill user leaves page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php, jquery

I have custom popup form, when the user click on 'get in touch' button i am showing popup to fill the form, once user submitted the form i am showing thanku popup.So if the user again click on 'get in touch' button form popup is coming but i need to show thanku popup only because the user already submitted the form. i need to have this functionality until he user leaves the page.

pls help me to achive this.

```
My phtml file
```

```
<div id="popup-modal"> 
<div class="contact-form-popup" style="display:none;">

    <form class="form contact"
          action=""
          id="contact-form"
          method="post"
          data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
          data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'
          autocomplete="off">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Get in touch')) ?></span></legend>
            <br/>
            <div class="field note no-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Simply fill in your details and enquiry below and one of our team will be in touch as soon as possible.')) ?></div>
            <div class="field firstname ">
                <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your Name')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="name" id="name" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Name')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="field emailaddress ">
                <label class="label" for="emailaddress"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer email address')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field mobile">
                <label class="label" for="mobile"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone number')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="mobile" id="mobile" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone number')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field postcode">
                <label class="label" for="postcode"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer postcode')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="postcode" id="postcode" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Customer postcode')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field enquiry ">
                <label class="label" for="enquiry"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Enquiry')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea name="enquiry" id="enquiry" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Enquiry')) ?>"
                        class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="field extension ">
                <input type='hidden' name="extension" id="extension-name"
                       class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" id='customer-contact' title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Submit')) ?>"
                        class="action submit primary">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div style="display:none" class="static-block-message">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Get in touch')) ?></span></legend>
            <br/>
    <div class="field note no-label">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Simply fill in your details and enquiry below and one of our team will be in touch as soon as possible.')) ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Thanku you.A member of our team will be in touch shortly.'))?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function($, modal) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                
                buttons: []
            };
            var openModal = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));

            jQuery('body').on('click', '.demo-banner .pagebuilder-button-primary', function(){
                jQuery('.contact-form-popup').show();
                jQuery('.static-block-message').hide();
                jQuery('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
            });

            jQuery('body').on('click', '#contact-form .action.submit', function(e){

                    e.preventDefault();
                    //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    if(!(jQuery('#contact-form').valid())){
                        return false
                    };
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: '<?php echo $block->getUrl("popup/action/index") ?>',
                        data: jQuery('#contact-form').serialize(),
                        cache: false,
                        showLoader: 'true',
                        success: function(response) {
                            //alert('success');
                            jQuery('.contact-form-popup').hide();
                            jQuery('.static-block-message').show();
                            
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                
            });
        });
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Most easy solution for this is to create install schema new table in customer table and maintain a key in database with value of 1 and 0 and based on this you can switch the popup.

Comment: Hi @Prits, thanks for your responce, can you explain littile bit more. And i am  not storing the form data in the database.

Comment: Hello @Mani No issues i assume it will used to send mail for logged in user so do one thing add a new column with default value of 0 in customer entity table use for ref. https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/add-new-field-in-customer_entity-table-magento-2-using-db_schema-xml/ link and then in you mail controller file when mail success does just update that field with true or 1 so based on that value you can show the popup like if value is 0 then show mail popup and if 1 then show thankyou popup. i hope it helps.